# Content div is higher than elements inside

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a website and i'm trying to center elements vertically in a div following this tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_center-vertical.

The content technically does get centered. Problem is: the content div gets higher than the content itself, so in reality it's not completely centered, giving problems in mobile screens.

Unluckily have no idea how it happens or how resolve it.

Html section:

```
<div class="banner-item-content">
<img src="https://alto.7180.eu/modules/custombanners/views/img/uploads/b09df371daff098e783367d788f96a20731083b9.PNG" alt="Banner1" class="banner-img">
<div class="custom-html"> <!--div to center-->
<h1 style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Prodotto 1</span></h1>
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</span></p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><span><a href="https://alto.7180.eu/it/34-donna" class="btn btn-default"><span>SHOP NOW</span></a></span></p> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS that does the centering:

```
.banner-item-content div.custom-html{
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Here's the link to the website to check it directly: https://alto.7180.eu/it/. You can see the problem in the first banner that says "Prodotto 1" (skip the slider).

I would just like to understand which way i can avoid having this empty space included in the centered div, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add display flex to banner item content , it will align center.

```css
.banner-item-content {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you really much!! If it's not too much, Do you mind giving me a brief explanation? Thanks!

Comment: By giving display flex, we’re telling the browser that everything in the div should be rendered with flex instead of the default display.

For more info visit 
https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/flexbox/#flex-containers

Please test it in all browsers, to verify